# Making columns from a string in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm going to distinguish values and make them columns through a string column.
my string format is as below :

||1|21|-1|-1|-1|0||||

I already have tried to using instr or regexp_instr but as in some rows the first character is null ,it returns wrong data.here the separator is '|' .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqKyv.jpg)

It's appreciated if you could help me into this issue.

Comment: anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**:

```
WITH sample_data ( "COMMENT" ) AS (
  SELECT '||1|21|-1|-1|-1|0||||' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) AS col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) AS col3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1 ) AS col4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1 ) AS col5,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 6, NULL, 1 ) AS col6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 7, NULL, 1 ) AS col7,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 8, NULL, 1 ) AS col8,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 9, NULL, 1 ) AS col9,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 10, NULL, 1 ) AS col10,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 11, NULL, 1 ) AS col11,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( "COMMENT", '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 12, NULL, 1 ) AS col12
FROM   sample_data;
```

**Output**:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 COL7 COL8 COL9 COL10 COL11 COL12
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----- ----- -----
          1    21   -1   -1   -1   0
```

Comment: many thanks and appreciations ,it works as well .best regards

Comment: anybody can help me?